# Convert Rows into Columns with Columns Grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to implement following below, but don't know where to start:

I have the following output from SQL query:

```
LocationID     ItemID     ItemName     Price1     Price2 
---------------------------------------------------------
1               101        A             100         150 
1               102        B             220         170 
2               103        C             120         155 
2               104        D             123         160 
3               105        E             158         179 
3               106        F             160         180
```

Now I want to make my output to look like this:

```
                           LocationID 1           LocationID 2
ItemID     ItemName     Price1     Price2     Price1     Price2 
---------------------------------------------------------
101        A             100         150      0           0 
102        B             220         170      0           0 
103        C             0           0        120         155 
104        D             0           0        123         160
105        E             0           0        0           0
106        F             0           0        0           0
```

How can I do the same in SQL, appreciate if someone can guide me.

P.S ItemID & ItemName are coming from one master table joined with LocationID.

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: You can do this with a cross tab, also known as conditional aggregation. The first question though, is there always exactly two locations? If the number of locations varies it takes a different approach.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, the location are fixed here

Comment: I was about to post an answer to this but it doesn't make sense. You have the same number of rows in the output. And for every single row in the output Location 2 values are the same. What should they be? And where do they come from??

Comment: @SeanLange Ohh..Sorry, I have corrected my post now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said...conditional aggregation.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

CREATE TABLE #Something
(
    LocationID int
    , ItemID int
    , ItemName char(1)
    , Price1 int
    , Price2 int
)

insert #Something
select 1, 101, 'A', 100, 150 union all
select 1, 102, 'B', 220, 170 union all
select 2, 103, 'C', 120, 155 union all
select 2, 104, 'D', 123, 160 union all
select 3, 105, 'E', 158, 179 union all
select 3, 106, 'F', 160, 180;

select LocationID
    , ItemName
    , Location1_Price1 = MAX(case when LocationID = 1 then Price1 else 0 end)
    , Location1_Price2 = MAX(case when LocationID = 1 then Price2 else 0 end)
    , Location2_Price1 = MAX(case when LocationID = 2 then Price1 else 0 end)
    , Location2_Price2 = MAX(case when LocationID = 2 then Price2 else 0 end)
from #Something
group by LocationID
    , ItemName
```

Comment: if I want to make my LocationID to be loaded dynamically, in that case what would I change in the above code?

Comment: You would start by providing ALL the details about the problem up front. Can you explain what you mean? Maybe provide some actual tables (like I did in the answer).

Comment: what I mean is if later I added another 20 LocationID, instead if hard coding the same, Can I bring it Dynamically from anther Master table, if So, what changes need to be done in the above query?

Comment: Still pretty vague on requirements here. I am guessing you would need to use a dynamic cross tab. You can read about how you can accomplish that here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/